# Intellij idea не может нормально генерировать Meta-inf

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Каждый раз когда я создаю проект и компилирую его intellij idea не генерирует meta-inf, а если и генерирует, то он поломан и приходиться танцевать с бубном чтобы он скомпилировал нормально

Comment: Используйте Maven и голова не будет болеть

Comment: Так дело в том что я использую maven

Comment: Тогда рассказывайте, как вы это делаете